# Can Macbook Pro (Late 2016, USB-C) screen be used as monitor for Raspberry Pi over USB-C with HDMI adapter?

Tags: raspbian, usb, hdmi, display, macos

I have a MacBook Pro 15" (Late 2016, Touch Bar and USB-C ports), and I want to sometimes use the screen as a monitor for my Raspberry Pi. I know that old MacBooks couldn't do this because the HDMI port is HDMI-out only, but USB-C seems like it should be able to be used as both input and output? Anyone have any ideas on how I can use this screen as a Raspberry Pi monitor? I have an HDMI to USB C adapter that I use for HDMI output on this MacBook, but no idea if that works the other way around.

Comment: I think the apple stackexchange site,  ask different,  might be a better place to ask this question.  Since this is more about the MacBook than the Pi.

Comment: You are asking (searching) for `Target Display Mode` which ["lets you use the built-in display on a supported iMac as an external display for another Mac."](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204592). According to available information, this works only for a few iMac Models. I never read about new MBP, that support this feature. If both, the RPi and the Mac are in the same network, you could use VNC, x11 forwarding, etc.

Answer (score 1):

No. Even though the USB-C plug is the same on both ends, the MacBook Pro can't act as a display.  You'll need to use remote desktop software like VNC if you want to see the Raspberry Pi's desktop on your laptop.